# Implementation of image upload and thumbnail generation on web app or on rest API?

Tags: php, performance, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the most effiecient and less resource implementation when uploading images to S3 having a restful API setup?

Should the web application handle the generation of thumbnails and upload to Amazon S3 and make an API request on successful upload?

[image]

OR

Should the web application pass the image request to the rest API to handle the generation of thumbnails and upload to Amazon S3 then save data to DB on success?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to write an amazon lambda function to deal with the image uploading, i.e.: [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/). This way you would only need to upload one image (saving on throughput) and amazon would seamlessly handle the image resizing separately from the api (as image handling, such as resizing and uploading, should ideally be a separate service).

Out of the two choices that you posted in your question, i would definitely choose the second one, because:

- You don't want your user to upload multiple images. UX, users data costs on mobile, uploading time, possibility of failing - everything increases dramatically if you let the web app handle this task
- you can have much more freedom and more sophisticated tools [like Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to work with your images.
- You can potentially handle uploading (to amazon) and resizing a-synchronically, further improving the perceived speed.